# Aligning two text views horizontally in a list item

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using two text views in my List Item to be used in a listview an android application.

However, the text views are displayed one below the other in each list item and I want to display them horizontally, in each item. Does using a Linear Layout help? Or is it possible to do so using a Relative Layout?

android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lnumber"
Using this in my second text view resulted in my text items printing vertically on the left end of the list item.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative layout take more time as compare to linear layout to inflate so use as you can as linear layout instead of relative layout.

Linear layout already aligned horizontally so you can directly use it.
And you can give weights too.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lnumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="Priyanka"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Madgundi"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add attribute `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lnumber"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lnumber"` to TextView `lname` to align it to right of `lnumber`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="First"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lnumber"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lnumber"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:text="Second"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]